# Unix cron job execution time

Tags: unix, time, cron

I need a command to get cron job execution time.

How long a particular script runs.

```
ps -ef | grep script name
```

will give us process state right

I want to know how long a script runs

Comment: I don't want to run script. Without running the script I want to the execution time of the script.

Comment: So... you want  to know how long something runs without actually running it? Unless this is a real time system where resources are guaranteed and always available I don't see how this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply You can print the time in a log file in your script like this,

```
 date >> /tmp/script.log
```

This needs to be done at starting of the script and ending of the script. 
Then you can know the total elapsed for the script. In intermediate time you can get to know how long the script is running.

Comment: Without editing the script I want to know the execution time.

Comment: And also without executing the time

Comment: And also without executing the  script

Comment: ps -ef command output field TIME tells us about execution of the command?

Answer (score 0):

> ps -ef command output field TIME tells us about execution of the
>   command?

Yes, the TIME field contains the cumulated CPU time used by the process; see: [In Unix, what do the output fields of the ps command mean?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afnv)

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to know the elapsed execution `ETIME` of the process rather than its cumulative CPU `TIME`:

```
ps -e -o etime -o args | awk '/[s]cript_name/{ print $1 }'
```

See [the *ps* specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) for more info about format options.

For regular data collection, you might consider wrapping the cron job in a script which logs the elapsed time or start/stop times.  Sometimes this is not necessary, as the *crond* setup on some systems already does this for you (e.g., Redhat-ish `cron.hourly` script invocation logs the start and stop time of individual hourly jobs).